# Selector for descendents including the element itself

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wonder if there is something easier in order to achieve this (the selection of descendents plus the element itself):

```
<div id="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

#parent, #parent * {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If I would have an existing rule for many classes e.g.

```
.b20120411,
.b20120630,
.b20120711,
.b20121010,
.b20130109,
.b20121214 {
    ...
 }
```

and would like to have it for the descendents as well it would get messy:

```
.b20120411, .b20120411 *,
.b20120630, .b20120630 *,
.b20120711, .b20120711 *,
.b20121010, .b20121010 *,
.b20130109, .b20130109 *,
.b20121214, .b20121214 * {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nope; so far as I know that's the easiest it gets, I'm afraid.

Comment: you could add a common class name for all those elements and define a style on that common class

Comment: You ***can*** have more than one class name. So add a class name to all those items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only:

```
<div id="grand-parent">
    <div id="parent">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>


#grand-parent * {
    background-color: red;
}
```